# Config <set-variable> with xpath gives empty string while extracting from xml payload

Tags: java, xml, xpath, mule, mule-flow

I am working on a service which add the detials sent in the request to to two different queues.

For this I use  to extract part of the XML without disturbing the payload.
But it is giving blank.

My input looks as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://example.org/HelloService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <AddRequest>
      <Person>
         <firstName>Test</firstName>
         <lastName>Tesst</lastName>
         <age>23</age>
      </Person>
      <Company>
         <companyName>Test</companyName>
         <state>Tesst</state>
         <zip>12345</zip>
      </Company>
     </AddRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And part of my flow which is extracting the Person element is as below.

```
    <set-variable value="#[xpath://Person]" variableName="person"></set-variable>

    <logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars['person']]" />     
    ........
    ......
```

But the logger is printing it as blank

```
2013-01-30 12:56:08,287 INFO  [HelloService.stage1.02] processor.LoggerMessageProcessor (LoggerMessageProcessor.java:108) -
```

Any idea why it is extracting blank space instead of the xml element.

How can I get the "Person"  element from the paylaod using XPATH?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using the XSLT transformer to extract the xml element.

```
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Person" />                   
    </xsl:copy>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />                  
    </xsl:copy>     
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @user1985027  I have tried the XSLT and it is working. I want to try somthing directly inside the mule flow, instead of moving out of the flow.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
<set-variable value="#[xpath('//Person')]" variableName="person" />
```

**EDIT:**

```
<set-variable value="#[xpath('//Person').text]" variableName="person" />
```

will return text value of an element, if it has one.

Comment: It gave me org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement@23194cf5 [Element: <per:Person uri: http://example.org/HelloService/ attributes: []/>].  This will not serve my purpose. I need the Person element as XML.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check now if it serves your purpose.

Comment: .text addition resulted in empty space again. INVOCATION scoped properties: person=

Comment: I see, `.text` will return value only if an element has one. There should be a transformer to convert object to xml

Comment: I tried even that. But the result xml is a big 80 line xml of dom4j, but not Person element xml. <org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement> <qname serialization="custom"> <org.dom4j.QName> <string>per</string> <string>http://example.org/HelloService/person</string> <default>..............

Comment: What is the next step after getting <Person>. Where will you feed it?

Comment: as of now I will be placing the Person xml in a JMS queue.

Comment: How do you plan to push a variable value into JMS queue. Don't you need to update your payload for that?

Comment: Looks like you need a transformer like this or something else `<xm:xpath-extractor-transformer expression="//person" resultType="NODESET" />` rather than a `set-variable`. @dossot please enlighten :)

Comment: this transformer gave me   com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMNodeList.  :(